# Oracle/SQL PLUS: How to spool a log and write intermittently throughout script

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Figuring out how to spool to a file has been easy enough.  I am hoping there is an option to write to the text file after each command is written.  I am not sure how to communicate the status of a long script to other people on my team.  The solution we were going for was to write a log file to a network drive, as the script executes they would be able to follow along.

However, this seems to only write output to the file after the spool off; command at the end of the file.

Is there any way to achieve what we're trying to do, either with spooling a log file or another method?

Here is the code I have so far.

```
set timing on;
set echo on;

column date_column new_value today_var
select to_char(current_timestamp, 'yyyymmdd_HH24_MI') as date_column
  from dual
/
select current_timestamp from dual;

SPOOL 'Z:\log\KPI\secondary_reporting_&today_var..log'

... lots of stuff...
spool off;
```

Comment: You might want to put intermediate SPOOL OFFs followed by SPOOL <logfile> APPEND, where <logfile> is the same file for all instances of this command.

Comment: >> I am not sure how to communicate the status of a long script to other people on my team   << use v$longops to write status messages showing the progress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two methods come to mind, depending on what your 'stuff' is.

1) If your code has lots of SQL statements and PL/SQL blocks then you can repeatedly spool for a little while. Use the `spool <filename> append` statement for this.

```
SQL> help spool

 SPOOL
 -----

 Stores query results in a file, or optionally sends the file to a printer.
 In iSQL*Plus, use the Preferences screen to direct output to a file.

 SPO[OL] [file_name[.ext] [CRE[ATE] | REP[LACE] | APP[END]] | OFF | OUT]

 Not available in iSQL*Plus
```

2) If you have long running PL/SQL procedures use the `UTL_FILE` package. See https://docs.oracle.com/html/B14258_02/u_file.htm for more information. This does require some setup and administrative privileges in the database to set up a directory where writing is allowed.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there's no way to control when spooled output is written to a file. One way around this, though, could be to abandon spooling altogether and just redirect the output:

```
$ sqlplus @/path/to/script.sql >& /path/to/script.log
```